# Accessing `mate-terminal` through `ssh -X` on stretch-lite

Tags: ssh, terminal

My main computer runs under Ubuntu 16.04. I just installed Raspbian Stretch-Lite on a RPi 3B and try to access it through the network. I installed `emacs`, `xterm` and `mate-terminal`.

From my Ubuntu, `ssh -X pi@192.168.8.121 xterm` works fine: I'm requested to give the password and I see the `xterm` window displayed on the screen. The same holds for `emacs`. Yet `ssh -X pi@192.168.8.121 mate-terminal` fails: after providing the passwords there is a short delay of one second and I get the prompt back without anything on the screen.

I had a look at `/var/log/auth` which shows on line **04** why I don't get anything on the screen: while using `mate-terminal` I get disconnected for some reason while I don't get disconnected using `xterm` or `emacs`.

```
01 Aug 15 14:05:04 rpi-01 sshd[4572]: Accepted password for pi from 192.168.8.103 port 54746 ssh2
02 Aug 15 14:05:04 rpi-01 sshd[4572]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
03 Aug 15 14:05:04 rpi-01 systemd-logind[341]: New session c21 of user pi.
04 Aug 15 14:05:05 rpi-01 sshd[4584]: Received disconnect from 192.168.8.103 port 54746:11: disconnected by user
05 Aug 15 14:05:05 rpi-01 sshd[4584]: Disconnected from 192.168.8.103 port 54746
06 Aug 15 14:05:05 rpi-01 sshd[4572]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pi
07 Aug 15 14:05:05 rpi-01 systemd-logind[341]: Removed session c21.
```

Any idea ?

### Update to answer the question from @Ingo

After login on the pi with `ssh -vv -X pi@192.168.8.121` and issuing `mate-terminal`, I get

```
pi@rpi-01> mate-terminal
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from ::1 55300
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 4 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from ::1 55302
debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
debug2: channel 2: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 2: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 2: obuf empty
debug2: channel 2: close_write
debug2: channel 2: output drain -> closed
debug1: channel 2: FORCE input drain
debug2: channel 2: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 2: send eof
debug2: channel 2: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 2: send close
debug2: channel 2: rcvd close
debug2: channel 2: is dead
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: x11, nchannels 3
debug2: channel 1: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 1: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 1: obuf empty
debug2: channel 1: close_write
debug2: channel 1: output drain -> closed
debug1: channel 1: FORCE input drain
debug2: channel 1: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 1: send eof
debug2: channel 1: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 1: send close
/home/pi
pi@rpi-01> debug2: channel 1: rcvd close
debug2: channel 1: is dead
debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 1: free: x11, nchannels 2
```

If I do the same with `xterm`, the output is different:

```
pi@rpi-01> xterm
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from ::1 55304
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
debug2: channel 1: rcvd adjust 38628
debug2: channel 1: rcvd adjust 49152
... Many lines like this one
debug2: channel 1: rcvd adjust 33684
debug2: channel 1: window 2047856 sent adjust 49296
--> Here the xterm opens
```

For `mate-terminal` the lines below appear twice

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from ::1 55300
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
```

Then, it looks like the RPi side doesn't send any data and thus there's nothing to read

```
debug2: channel 2: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 2: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 2: obuf empty
debug2: channel 2: close_write
debug2: channel 2: output drain -> closed
```

and all the links are closed.

**Just as a reminder**, what is installed on the RPi is the  Raspbian Stretch-Lite, meaning the bare minimum, without X11 and all that stuff. I installed the additional softwares by hand : `sudo apt install xterm mate-terminal`. Maybe there is some missing stuff on the RPi side to have `mate-terminal` working properly...

Comment: My simple test to try to duplicate the problem went fine, with the `mate-terminal` window appearing on my local display.  However, I do get the `disconnected by user` message in my remote `/var/log/auth.log` when I try a command that does not exist on the remote side... perhaps `mate-terminal` is not installed? ... try `ssh pi@192.168.8.121 which mate-terminal`

Comment: If it hadn't been installed, you'd get: `ssh -X  pi@192.168.8.121 toto` -> `bash: toto: command not found`. But anyway, I checked: it is installed.

Comment: Are there any aliases set up... `ssh xxx@xxx alias` ... any other command combinations that may cause the command on the remote machine to exit?  The reason the `ssh` session closes is because the command has finished... thus the `disconnected by user` in auth.log

Comment: What gives you the verbose output with `ssh -vv -X pi@192.168.8.121 mate-terminal` (double v)?